# How to force a checkbox if user clicks it twice?

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, checkbox

Is it possible to have to two checkboxes appear as blank on pageload.
But if the user clicks an option, then they can never click off it - so at the moment the user can toggle between the options and you can only tick once. However if they press the ticked box twice it removes the tick.

**HTML**

```
My Billing Address is the same <input type="checkbox" class="sameCheck" name="toggleOracleAddress" id="toggleOracleAddress" value="SAME" /> <br /> <br />
My Billing Address is the different <input type="checkbox" class="sameDifferent" name="toggleOracleAddress" id="toggleOracleAddress" value="DIFFERENT" />
```

**jQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //////////////////
    //####     SAME ADDRESS
    //////////////////
    $('.sameCheck').click(function() {
        $('.sameDifferent').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#proceedIsOn').slideUp();
    });
    //////////////////
    //####     DIFFERENT ADDRESS
    //////////////////
    $('.sameDifferent').click(function() {
        $('.sameCheck').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#proceedIsOn').slideDown();    
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE HERE http://jsfiddle.net/mRwMt/

Comment: Use a radio button instead: `<input type="radio" ... >` -- they were designed to produce the exact behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Radio buttons were made for your exact reason. Use them - checkboxes aren't suitable for this.

Comment: @Blazemonger What an idiot. The poster asked for Checkboxes not radioboxes which we all know about. What was the point of downvoting? Daft

Comment: @M1th little harsh but true. I know what radio buttons are. I want to do this with checkboxes.

Comment: You're trying to force checkboxes with JavaScript to do something they weren't designed to do, which radio buttons are. More importantly, your users will EXPECT radio buttons to exhibit the behavior your want to implement, but will NOT expect checkboxes to behave this way and may think something is broken. You're trying to use a pliers as a hammer when the hammer is laying right next to you in the toolbox. Stop trying to be clever and use the right tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set it to checked on every click :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sameCheck').click(function() {
        this.checked = true;
        $('#proceedIsOn').slideUp();
    });
    $('.sameDifferent').click(function() {
        this.checked = true;
        $('#proceedIsOn').slideDown();    
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mRwMt/1/)

or to avoid the sliding as well :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sameCheck').click(function() {
        if (!this.checked) return false;
        $('#proceedIsOn').slideUp();
    });
    $('.sameDifferent').click(function() {
        if (!this.checked) return false;
        $('#proceedIsOn').slideDown();    
    });
});​
```

Or to just toggle between boxes :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sameCheck').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).siblings('input[type"text"]').prop('checked', false);
            $('#proceedIsOn').slideUp();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.sameDifferent').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).siblings('input[type"text"]').prop('checked', false);
            $('#proceedIsOn').slideDown();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mRwMt/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){

     var otherBox = $("input:checkbox").not(this);

     if($(this).is(":checked"))  otherBox.hide();
     else   otherBox.show();

     //rest of your code...

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mRwMt/2/

---

More advanced fiddle that hides the whole line: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mRwMt/3/

Comment: this looks like an extremely poorly designed mutual exclusive checkbox to be honest...